# Issues with Nvidia drivers on Dell Inspiron 7567

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, inspiron, xserver

so I've been trying to make my Nvidia drivers run on my linux machine for some deep learning capabilities. Problem is that laptops and especially dell Inspirons have isssues with drivers on unix systems. I've looked up a bunch of solutions and nothing worked.

Currently I am running the 410.48 drivers (I'll get to this later) but the problem is that Nvidia X Server doesnt work at all.

Here's what it says when I do try to run **nvidia-settings**:

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

This happens regardless if I am running on intell or Nvidia GPU, it seems its unable to pick up anything from the system.

Now interestingly enough it *seems* that the Nvidia SMI works:

```
Thu Oct  4 20:19:25 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.48                 Driver Version: 410.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  4040MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The interesting this is that the Nvidia driver running is 410.48 yet I had no clue such driver existed. Regardless the Nvidia X Server issue remain regardless of driver version.
I've already tried 390 | 396 | 340 etc. 
Problem with anything older than 390 is this violent screen flicker and being unable to boot into GUI until I purge the Nvidia drivers and boot into nouvau drivers.

*Its been a week now and I am honestly at the end of my wits here. I've searched everywhere and nothing. This thread is my last attempt.*

Comment: If you run `sudo prime-select nvidia` then reboot, does the `nvidia-settings` work after that?

Comment: Don't login with the Wayland option, that switches to the integrated video (i915?).  Did you try the CUDA samples anyway -- the non graphical ones may still successfully run when the video is using the i915.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on the same laptop. I fixed it by removing the `nomodeset` parameter from the file `/etc/default/grub`.

So the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

should be changed to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot the laptop.